# Should I use independent- or propensity score matching?

Tags: propensity-scores, matching, observational-study

I work on data form an observational study (n=34) and want to compare the outcome of the individuals to an historic cohort (n=600). Subjects in the observational study received additional treatment compared to the historical cohort. I collected data on disease type, disease intensity, response and demographics for both groups.

Now, I want to perform survival-analysis using the Kaplan-Meier-Estimator, comparing both groups overall and matched 1:1, 1:2. Could you advise on the recommended matching method to use for matching the 34 subjects of the observational study to the historical cohort, to adjust for disease type, disease intensity, and response?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use whatever matching method yields the best balance. Sometimes that will be propensity score matching and sometimes it will be some other form of matching. I recommend genetic matching, which optimizes balance. Ideally you will retain the largest sample size you can, so you should try multiple different matching ratios (e.g., 1:1, 1:2, 1:10, etc.) to find the one that yields the greatest remaining sample size and balance.

Read the `MatchIt` [vignette](https://kosukeimai.github.io/MatchIt/articles/matching-methods.html) on matching methods, which provides a guide on all the matching methods available in the package and how to choose among them and customize them. It's good that you are not blindly using propensity score matching just because it is the most common matching method, but the specific matching methods that will work best for your data must be discovered by trying multiple and comparing their performance at balancing the covariates.